# Changed SSHD port in VPS can't login

Tags: centos, ssh, vps

I altered the SSHD port on my unmanaged CentOS VPS to `0062`, now I am unable to SSH in and get the error: `Network error: connection refused`.

Does anyone know how to get in and fix this? And why changing the port to this has stopped me from connecting?

Note: The VPS is hosted externally

Comment: Are you sure you changed both the firewall and the daemon?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used [centmin mod](http://centminmod.com/) to perform the changes which said it performed all the necessary changes, I am not 100% positive but it sure did seem to change a lot.

Comment: Did you try to use `nmap` to look for opened port. Also on many languages having a number starting with 0 means it should be interpreted as octal, did you try then to connect to port 50 instead (62 in octal is 50 in decimal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of things could of have happened. A few things come to mind:

- Your firewall is still blocking the connection.
- Another service is running on port 62
- You did not restart the service after changing the value
- ...

Try connecting via the out-of-band console (if you have one) and alter what needs to be changed (firewall, settings, ...). To test wether or not your firewall is bugging you, stop it for a little while and see if you can get in (`service iptables stop`)

I'm also not sure about putting `0062` as a port. You might need to put `62` instead.

If you are unable to get into the out-of-band, ask your provider to have a look. Otherwise, you will have to reimage the machine.

The script should indeed change both the port on the firewall and in the config for ssh:

```
sed -i 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_dsa_key/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_dsa_key/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#PubkeyAuthentication/PubkeyAuthentication/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#RSAAuthentication/RSAAuthentication/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#AuthorizedKeysFile/AuthorizedKeysFile/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#IgnoreRhosts yes/IgnoreRhosts yes/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#PermitEmptyPasswords no/PermitEmptyPasswords no/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

/usr/sbin/sshd -t

service sshd restart

iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport $PORTNUM -j ACCEPT

service iptables restart
```

However, the `0062` might of have b0rked one or maybe both of them. Try getting back into your machine first.

Comment: I now realise I made an error with `0062` but I assume it would be read as `62`, I used [centmin mod](http://centminmod.com/) to perform the change which said it successfully updated my firewall. I'm not sure what you mean by out-of-band console, I have a serial console on my VPS control panel however that is hardcoded to access via port 22.

Comment: Isn't there a console you can use that doesn't rely on SSH? If you get in, please post the results for `iptables -L -v -n` and `netstat -tulpen` in your opening post.

Answer (score 3):

0062 could be interpreted as octal...which would be port 50.  Try connecting on port 50.  I doubt it will work, but worth a try.

Who is the VPS hosted with?  Most of them give you either a web console which doesn't connect via SSH, or at least a way to boot your system from a rescue CD where you could go in and change the config file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's also quite possible that some tools interpreted it as octal and some didn't. So the firewall and the daemon may not agree on the port. :(

Comment: [x10vps](http://x10vps.com), I'm afraid port 50 didn't work but you did manage to get my hopes up for a second :). They provide a serial console in my VPS control panel but is seems hardwired on to port 22.

Comment: You should be able to access the Serial Console, it's always hardwired to 22 because it doesn't listen to your ssh-server, but to an out-of-band-console on the host of your VPS.

Comment: @Bart De Vos you're right it was my java that was messing up. I managed to get in via serial console. I used the same script to set the port to 62 which had the same issue as before, but when I put back to 22 everything works as expected. I'm thinking I should perhaps just leave it at 22 and that added security through obscurity isn't THAT important.

Comment: changing port numbers has a very low improvement on security. If you really want to lock down the server disable interactive password ssh logins and only allow SSH public/private key logins. That makes it so bots/hackers/etc cannot try brute force password breaking.

Answer (score 2):

If the the tips by others about firewall and `netstat -tulpen` output do not help you, there's yet another detail that can be wrong.

If SELinux is enabled, it can block sshd accessing ports other than 22. Check that out with

```
semanage port -l | grep ssh
```

Should that return only 22, you can add more ports to SELinux sshd rule with

```
semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 62
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you specify the port when connecting to it via `ssh`?

```
ssh -p 62 user@example.com
```

`ssh` expects to connect to port 22 by default and if you changed this, you need to tell your applications.

Comment: Yep, I am using PuTTY to SSH in on port 62