# Can't SSH to VPS (timeout)

Tags: ssh, vps, timeout

I was able to SSH into my VPS earlier today, and made no major changes. However now when I attempt to SSH into my VPS it doesn't even ask me for my password it just times out.

If I open the serial console and attempt to SSH via localhost it works fine. I have also pinged my hostname and ip address and both of these show the server is up.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Is your `sshd` running?

Comment: Sounds like either a FW issue or the SSH/OpenSSH service is down, is the process running?

Comment: @BartDeVos `ps -A | grep ssh` returns
`3748 ?        00:00:00 sshd
17478 pts/0    00:00:00 ssh
17479 ?        00:00:00 sshd
17481 ?        00:00:00 sshd` Honestly I have no idea what this means (am a newbie)

Comment: @BartDeVos I also restarted sshd to be safe still nothing

Comment: @Chopper3 What is FW?

Comment: @GeorgeReith A FireWall

Comment: FW = Firewall, ;-)

Comment: @Chopper3 oh yeh... duh :P

Comment: What OS?  Is it just SSH that is not working or are all services unavailable?  e.g. if you have an HTTPD daemon can you browse the site or connect via telnet to port 80/443?  What is the output of `ssh -vv <IP address>`?  What does `telnet <IP address> 22` give?  Please add the output to your question, adding it as a comment will not be very readable.  Can you also post the output of `ps auxwww|grep ssh|grep -v grep` and `sudo netstat -nap|grep sshd`?  The `ps -A` output might show existing ssh connections and not the required SSH daemon.

Comment: This does not correllate to your other open question? http://serverfault.com/questions/387056/changed-sshd-port-in-vps-cant-login

Comment: @Michuelnik that was a seperate issue, it does sort of correlate as I'm in discussion with Joseph Kern and hes found the issue which was something I did during that question which broke it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Things to check:

1. **Check your route;** on your client run `traceroute <ip>`
2. **Check your name resolution;** on your client and server run `dig <hostname>`
3. **Check your firewall;** on your server run `iptables --list` (test ssh with your client firewall disabled as well)
4. **Restart the service;** `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` (or whatever is appropriate for your distro)

Beyond those issues there could be a few more, including errors or outages at the VPS provider.

Comment: Ok all of those are checking out ok (still no SSH) apart from I am unable to run `iptables --list` it doesn't understand that command.

Comment: run `which iptables`, you might need to run `sudo iptables --list`

Comment: `which iptables` returns `/usr/bin/which: no iptables in (/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin)` and `sudo iptables ---list` returns `sudo: iptables: command not found`

Comment: Did you turn off your client-side firewall? (strange that you don't have `iptables` installed, which distro is this?)

Comment: CentOS 5.5 32bit, I installed [centmin mod](http://www.centminmod.com/)

Comment: Did you turn off your client-side firewall?

Comment: Nope, I do have iptables... `sudo etc/init.d/iptables status` gives me a massive list of firewall settings .etc however I have no idea what I'm looking for

Comment: What does this command return? `netstat --tcp --listening --programs | grep -i ssh`

Comment: `tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:acas                      *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:re-mail-ck                *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:acas                      *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:re-mail-ck                *:*                         LISTEN      17601/sshd`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3386/discussion-between-joseph-kern-and-george-reith)